# Pyspark - Read data inside a map function?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataframe as below:

```
id  | file_path
--------------------------
abc | s3://data/file1.json
def | s3://data/file2.json
```

**For every row in this dataframe, I want to read the contents of the file located in `file_path` in a distributed manner.**

Here's what I tried:

```
rdd_paths = df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.file_path)

rdd_contents = rdd_paths.map(lambda y: spark.read.parquet(y))

rdd_contents.take(2)
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

I checked `SPARK-5063` but did not get clear pointers to solve this. How can I read from the file paths in a distributed manner?

Answer (score 0):

Spark context can only be accessed from driver node, since `map()` is executed in the worker nodes, it doesnt have access to `spark` in your code that does `spark.read.parquet(y)`.

You need to modify you logic, for example(not a very good example) you can  the column values for s3 paths, pass this to `textFile` which provide `key` as file name and `value` as file content.

```
paths = df.select('file_path').collect()
rdd4 = sc.textFile(paths)
```

Now, you can apply map or iterate to store `values` (file content) as columns in the dataframe. For example with join.

```
rdd4.foreach(f=>{
    println(f)
 })
```